# LimitToLast() freezes unity

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm usig Unity 2018.3.0f2
Firebase 6.3

The problem is without using limitToLast() the code below works fine. I can get all data which Is thousands of data.
But I need to limit it and when I put 1 or 10 or any number with limittoLast or LimitToFirst (10) unity give no response and after waiting or stop to run the Unit play cpu starts to run faster, unity Freezes and I have to stop unity from Task manager and restart. Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
 FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
          .GetReference("users").OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(100)
          .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>{ 
    if (task.IsFaulted)
              {
                 Debug.LogError("failed");
              }
    else if (task.IsCompleted)
              { Debug("success")} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `GetValueAsync()` which will override your `LimitToLast()` clause and grab all the data in the "users" reference.

This code should get you closer to what you want:

```
DatabaseReference usersReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users");
Query query = usersReference.OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(100);
query.ValueChanged += (object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) =>
{
    // this lambda will get called up to 100 times
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    Debug.Log(args.Snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
};
```